# Set NSManagedObject to nil;

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

By tapping a cell in `tableView` I am creating new `NSManagedObject` instance and do rollback to the previous `viewController`:

```
User *user = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.delegate setSupervisorGUID:user.server_id supervisorTitle:user.name];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

at the same `viewController` I have a cancel button what else rollback to the previous `viewController` but without setting new object (zeroing User object):

```
[self.delegate setSupervisorGUID:[NSNull null] supervisorTitle:@"User not set"];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This way does the trick but I think it's logically incorrect and I also have a warning here. How can I do this in right way?

**UPDATE**

warning is:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSNull *' to parameter of type
>   'NSString *'

Here is the definition of `-setSupervisorGUID:supervisorTitle:`

```
- (void) setSupervisorGUID:(NSString *) supervisorId supervisorTitle:(NSString *) supervisorTitle
{
    if ([formData[@"visit_type_id"] isEqualToString:supervisorId]) return;

    [formData setObject:supervisorId forKey:@"supervisor_id"];
    [formData setObject:supervisorTitle forKey:@"supervisorTitle"];
    supervisorCell.detailTextLabel.text = supervisorTitle;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: How is the `setSupervisorGUID:supervisorTitle:` delegate method defined, and what warning do you get?

Comment: `NSNull` is intended to *only* be used to denote an *empty* value in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNull *` *is* incompatible to `NSString *`. But you can call

```
[self.delegate setSupervisorGUID:nil supervisorTitle:@"User not set"];
```

instead and check for `supervisorId == nil` in the delegate method.